# Is there any way to keep a PeriodIndex as a series of Periods with a reset_index()?

Tags: python, pandas

I've noticed that for a `DataFrame` with a `PeriodIndex`, the month reverts to its native `Int64` type upon a `reset_index()`, losing its `freq` attribute in the process. Is there any way to keep it as a `Series` of `Period`s?

For example:

```
In [42]: monthly
Out[42]: 
                    qunits  expend     
month   store upc                                                         
1992-12 1     21        83  248.17  
              72         3   13.95  
              78         2    6.28  
              79         1    5.82  
              85         5   28.10  
              87         1    1.87  
              88         6   11.76  
...
1994-12 151   857       12   81.48  
              858       23  116.15  
              880        7   44.73  
              881       13   25.05  
              883       21   67.25  
              884       44  190.56  
              885       13   83.57  
              887        1    4.55
```

becomes:

```
In [43]: monthly.reset_index()
Out[43]: 
        month  store   upc  qunits  expend     
0         275      1    21      83  248.17  
1         275      1    72       3   13.95  
2         275      1    78       2    6.28  
3         275      1    79       1    5.82  
4         275      1    85       5   28.10  
5         275      1    87       1    1.87  
6         275      1    88       6   11.76  
7         275      1    89      21   41.16  
...
500099    299    151   857      12   81.48  
500100    299    151   858      23  116.15  
500101    299    151   880       7   44.73  
500102    299    151   881      13   25.05  
500103    299    151   883      21   67.25  
500104    299    151   884      44  190.56  
500105    299    151   885      13   83.57  
500106    299    151   887       1    4.55
```

**Update 6/13/2014**
It worked beautifully but the end result I need is the `PeriodIndex` values to be passed onto a grouped `DataFrame`. I got it to work but it seems to me that it could be done more compactly. I.e., my code is:

```
periods_index = monthly.index.get_level_values('month')
monthly.reset_index(inplace=True)
monthly.month = periods_index
grouped=monthly.groupby('month')
moments=pd.DataFrame(monthly.month.unique(),columns=['month'])
for month,group in grouped:
  moments.loc[moments.month==month,'meanNo0']=wmean(group[group.relative!=1].avExpend,np.log(group[group.relative!=1].relative))
```

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
periods_index = monthly.index.get_level_values('month')
```